# How to get specific number of characters after a string from a string in php

Tags: php, string

I have the following statement;

`DELIMITER $$` I want to get the '$$'(Next two charchters after the Delimiter) part from the string. There is always a space between the word and the symbol.

Comment: can you post a sample string and a sample output

Comment: please specific what you want, so we can help you easily. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
preg_match('/DELIMITER (..)/', $string, $match);
$next_two_chars = $match[1];
```

`$match[n]` contains the part of the string that was matched by the `n`th capture group.

Answer (score 1):

If there's always a space between the two strings, you could simply use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode):

```
$result = trim(explode(' ', $string, 2)[1]);
```